# Example for converting numeric result of function to string with commas

Tags: sql, postgresql

I try to make TOTAL_MONEY to this format "123,456,789" (with commas).

```
select entity_id,
       'the sum is:' || to_char(TOTAL_MONEY, ',') as text_msg
from(
select entity_id,
       sum(volume) as TOTAL_MONEY
from procurement) t
```

but it doesn't work. I don't find [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-formatting.html) something useful.

Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet another, simpler solution:

```
select
  entity_id,
  to_char(TOTAL_MONEY, '"the sum is: "FM999,999,999,999') as text_msg
from(
  select entity_id, sum(volume) as TOTAL_MONEY
  from procurement) t
```

There are: `'FM'` option to remove unnecessary spaces; `"double-quoted string"` to print it as-is without replacements of any patterns/placeholders.

Answer (score 1):

```
    select entity_id,
    'the sum is:' || ltrim(rtrim(to_char(TOTAL_MONEY, '999,999,999,999'))) as text_msg
    from(
          select entity_id,
          sum(volume) as TOTAL_MONEY
          from procurement
        ) t
```